# Form to delete data from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, sql-delete

So I'm creating a small program with 2 forms, one to add data to a database, and one to delete from it. I've managed to create the first input form, but I'm slightly confused as to how I would get the second form to work. In the database "tasks" I have a table called "ID" which has the columns "ID", "Name" and "Hours"

Here's what the two HTML forms look like

```
<h2>Add Tasks</h2> 
<form action="test.php" method="get">
Name of Task: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
Hours: <input type="number" name="hours"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit">
</form>

<h2>Delete Tasks</h2> 
<form action="delete.php" method="get">
ID: <input type="number" name="ID"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

And the PHP for the first form "Add tasks" which inserts data

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "Tasks");


if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
};


if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

mysqli_select_db ($conn,"Tasks");
$name = $_GET['name'];
$hours = $_GET['hours'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO ID (Name, Hours) VALUES ('".$name."','". $hours."')";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


$query = "SELECT `Name` FROM `ID`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$x=0;
```

And the PHP for the second form which deletes tasks. This is the part that is not working

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
mysqli_select_db ($conn, "Tasks");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM ID (ID) VALUES ('".$id."')";

$query = "SELECT `Name` FROM `ID`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$x=0;
```

How should I format the PHP for the second button. I've basically reused the code for the first form. Do I need to differentiate it somehow from the first button? Currently the page is showing up completely blank. I'm a complete novice so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First you should add a name to the delete button to be able to identify it on server-side `isset($_GET["delete")`. And then you should make yourself familiar with SQL queries.

Comment: DELETE FROM ID (ID) VALUES  - i'm not familiar with that syntax. Also, see prepared statements in PHP/PDO/mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL Statement

> ```
> "DELETE FROM ID (ID) VALUES ('".$id."')"
> ```

is wrong.

It [should be](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp)

> ```
> DELETE FROM table_name
> WHERE some_column=some_value;
> ```

. So, change your statement to

```
DELETE FROM ID WHERE ID='$id'
```

### Suggestions

- You should use `POST` method for action which will result in data edit.
- You should check the input, make sure it did not contain SQL statement. A good way is to use `$stuff = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["stuff"])`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have name 'ID' in the form but your are trying to get 'id'. That could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

The sql statement for deletion should look something like the snippet below.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM ID WHERE `id`=".$id.";";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answers you should give different `name` to the both `form` `input` tags as

```
<h2>Add Tasks</h2> 
<form action="test.php" method="get">
    Name of Task: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
    Hours: <input type="number" name="hours"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit">
</form>

<h2>Delete Tasks</h2> 
<form action="delete.php" method="get">
    ID: <input type="number" name="ID"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete">
</form>
```

So for adding into database , you can use

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
    // your code here
}
```

And for deleting from database , you can use

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
    mysqli_select_db ($conn, "Tasks");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM ID (ID) WHERE ID='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' ;

    $query = "SELECT `Name` FROM `ID`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $x=0;
}
```

This will solve all the problems.

If you are using same **name** for the `type="submit"` in both **forms** than you can use `POST` method on one **form** and `GET` method on the other.

And yes `mysql_real_escape_string` is used to prevent **SQL INJECTION**.