# Button has to be pressed to activate php code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So the idea of this website is that when you press the button it deletes the corresponding row from the database. However, the issue with my code is that after the first press the button fills the id variable and then executes the php on the next press. How can I avoid this and get he php to fit and execute the php on the first press of the button?

Included is the HTML page with the php embedded:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2 style"text-align:center";>Please enter the item you want to add to the list below </h2>

<?php



$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {

    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$sql = "CREATE TABLE freezerinventory (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
item VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)";

if(isset($_POST['itemx'])) 

{

$itemvar = $_POST["itemx"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO freezerinventory (item)
VALUES ('$itemvar')";
    $add =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
else {
    $sql = "";
}




mysqli_close($conn);


?>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" class="needs-validation" novalidate method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="uname"></label>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemx" placeholder="Enter an item for the freezer here" name="itemx" required>

      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>

      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>

    </div>

    <button id = "SubmitButton" name = "SubmitButton" type="button submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to list</button>
</form>
    </div>








<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";
$aVar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','myDB');


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM freezerinventory";
$result = mysqli_query($aVar, $sql);



echo "<table><tr>
    <th>Item name</th>
    <th>Date added</th> 
    <th>remove</th>
  </tr>    "; 


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {

echo "      <tr><td>" . $row['item'] . "</td><td>" . $row['reg_date'] . "</td><td><form action='

' method='POST'>
<div class= 'input-group' > <div class='input-group-append'>


                <button class='btn btn-danger'  onclick='deleteitem()'  id = 'delete' type='submit'>Remove</button>

                <input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$row['id']." />

            </div></div>

</form></td></tr>";



}
    echo "</table>";
?>

 <script>

function deleteitem (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

    <?php 



    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $delete = "DELETE FROM freezerinventory WHERE id=$id";
   $del =  mysqli_query($conn, $delete);

        ?>
        }
        else {
    }
    </script> 

<script>

function myFunction() {
  confirm("I am an alert box!");
}

</script>

<script>

(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to

    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

    // Loop over them and prevent submission

    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using ajax?

Comment: you are using ajax code wrong way ! your codes are all in same page so, you dont need ajax or javascript if you dont mind reloading page, get rid of all that codes keep only php,  name your button to delete and check for button clicked with if statement. if delete button clicked then do your query. SEE HERE FOR AN EXAMPLE : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915637/form-to-delete-data-from-mysql-database-using-php IMPORTAND you are wide open to sql injections, use prepared statements to prevent from sql injections

Comment: I have been using embedded php because otherwise the GET or POST functions redirect me to the php page. How do I execute the php without redirecting to the php page?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a language that runs only on server-side.
It is different to javascript that runs on client-side (on the browser).

If you may notice, you will never see PHP code on other websites, because (if the website uses PHP) it is processed on the server side and the return is HTML+CSS only.

Nowaday we would not create a page like this. 
We would create what we call API using PHP. We would use REST-API strategy.

Let's say we would host this API on this address `www.mywebsite.com/myapi/myfreezerendoint.php`

And we would use JS to request or post to this endpoint with simple javascript function called `fetch("www.mywebsite.com/myapi/myfreezerendoint.php", { ... })`.

I found this interesting tutorial about PHP API with MySQL as database: https://webdamn.com/create-simple-rest-api-with-php-mysql/

I hope you enjoy! Keep it up

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate processing script and submit a form to the URL path 'onClick' of a button. You cannot directly call PHP function with JS code.

Answer (score -1):

I've corrected and beautified all of the code, minimized it and this should now be it:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {

    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "CREATE TABLE freezerinventory (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
item VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

if(isset($_POST['itemx'])) {
  $itemvar = $_POST["itemx"];
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO freezerinventory (item) VALUES ('?')");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $itemvar);
  $stmt->execute();
} else {
    //the 'itemx' post parameter isn't set, make an alert or something
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
      table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2 style"text-align:center";>Please enter the item you want to add to the list below </h2>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" class="needs-validation" novalidate method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="uname"></label>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemx" placeholder="Enter an item for the freezer here" name="itemx" required>

      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>

      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>

    </div>

    <button id = "SubmitButton" name = "SubmitButton" type="button submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to list</button>
</form>
    </div>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";
$aVar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','myDB');


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
  $delete = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM freezerinventory WHERE id= ?");
  $delete->bind_param("s", $_POST['id']);
  $delete->execute();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM freezerinventory";
$result = mysqli_query($aVar, $sql);
echo "<table><tr>
    <th>Item name</th>
    <th>Date added</th> 
    <th>remove</th>
  </tr>    "; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {
  echo "      <tr><td>" . $row['item'] . "</td><td>" . $row['reg_date'] . "</td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <div class= 'input-group' > <div class='input-group-append'>
        <button class='btn btn-danger'  onclick='deleteitem(".$row['id'].")' id='delete'>Remove</button>
        <input type='hidden' name='id'/>
    </div></div>
    </form></td></tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
?>
<script>
function deleteitem (id_data) {
  $.post('<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>', {id: id_data}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);  //callback data
  });
}

function myFunction() {
  confirm("I am an alert box!");
}

(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to

    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

    // Loop over them and prevent submission

    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It might still need some fixes and I left some unused html elements in there but in theory this should work. It makes use of `ajax` to send the data to `php`. You don't have to use `ajax` but this should in theory solve your problem. If you run into any issues just comment under my answer.

**NOTE:** Just to clarify, I didn't try this therefore there might be some errors in there.

Comment: May I know why my answer got downvoted?

Comment: I have an error on line 20 $stmt = $conn->prepare->("INSERT INTO freezerinventory (item) VALUES ('?')"); I believe people are downvoting you because they want me to use php on the server side and not on the client side.

Comment: Well php is a server side language so it can't be used on the client side, you can only send requests to the server side and get a response. I'll look into the error. What exactly does the error say?

Comment: @RichardStarZ remove the `->` between `prepare` and `("`. So then you have: `$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO freezerinventory (item) VALUES ('?')");`. I've corrected it in my answer.